# Spring XML files are not being found by Maven exec

Tags: java, spring, maven

Summary: I have a very basic Java 1.8 and Spring 4.0.5 project, I'm using Maven 3.2.3 to manage it.  Maven exec cannot seem to see my Spring context, even though it appears to me that it is in the classpath.

My spring context is in

```
<project root>/src/main/resources/spring/ch2-beans.xml
```

and I load it using:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/ch2-beans.xml");
```

after a "mvn clean compile" I see

```
<project root>/target/classes/spring/ch2-beans.xml
```

and when I run:

```
mvn -X exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.wiley.beginning.spring.ch2.Main"
```

I see the following debug output which makes me think the classpath is indeed correct:

```
[DEBUG] Collected project classpath [/Users/me/Documents/workspace/BeginningSpring/chapter2/spring-book-ch2/target/classes]
[DEBUG] Adding to classpath : file:/Users/me/Documents/workspace/BeginningSpring/chapter2/spring-book-ch2/target/classes/
```

Yet I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/ch2-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/ch2-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of sorting this out?  What I've posted above is the result of many different attempts to solve this, and I'm stumped by the error when it certainly appears that the file path should be in the classpath, so perhaps this is something that has changed since I last coded (a while ago..).  Thanks!

Update..
Thinking that it might be some classpath issue with exec:java I ran the same code inside a unit test, executed within maven.  Same error.  I've also tried loading the xml file as "classpath:/spring/ch2-beans.xml", did not fix it.

Comment: did you try to use new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/ch2-beans.xml"); instead of new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/ch2-beans.xml");?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with and without the forward slash, neither works unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

There was a hyphen in the file name of the Spring configuration I was trying to load, and it appears that the classloader won't accept that.  Hyphens are illegal in identifier names in Java, apparently this applies also to external resources.

Once I removed the hyphen from the xml file name, it was found.

On a related note, I'm pretty annoyed with the "Beginning Spring" book example which uses these hyphenated names.